# Why is __import__ causing my program to hang?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, logging, deadlock

I am working on a python app that uses the default python logging system. Part of this system is the ability to define handlers in a logging config file. One of the handlers for this app is the django admin email handler, "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler". When the app is initializing the logging system, it makes a call to logging.config.fileconfig. This is done on a background thread and attempts to reload the config file periodically. I believe that is important.

I have traced through the python logging source code down to the method:

```
def _resolve(name):
    """Resolve a dotted name to a global object."""
    name = name.split('.')
    used = name.pop(0)
    found = __import__(used)
    for n in name:
        used = used + '.' + n
        try:
            found = getattr(found, n)
        except AttributeError:
            __import__(used)
            found = getattr(found, n)
    return found
```

in the file python2.7/logging/config.py

When this function is given the paramater "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler" in order to create that handler, my app hangs on the command

```
__import__(used)
```

where used is "django".

I did a little research and I have seen some mentions of __import__ not being thread safe and to avoid its use in background threads. is this accurate? And knowing that __import__("django") does cause a deadlock, is there anything I could do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the default Django `LOGGING` setting to control logging.  For development, starting the server with `manage.py runserver` will automatically reload Django if any files are changed, including the settings file with the logging configuration.  In practice it works quite well!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples

Comment: It's something I am definitely considering.